# PHP:Setting a static member from a static class function

Tags: php, static-members

I have a Class. Inside this class, i have a private static member. I also have a protected class function as well as a public static class function.

Essentially, I'm trying to set the static member. The flow is this.

Inside the protected class function, there is a call to the other class function:
ex.

```
class MyClass extends someOtherClass{

     private static $myVar;      

     protected function login(){
         MyClass::createDBInstance();

     }

     public static function createDBInstance(){
         self::$myVar = 'someValue';
     }
 }
```

The problem I'm having, is that once it makes it into the createDBInstance, and tries to set the self::myVar, it kills. Am i overlooking something so fundamental?

Comment: When "it kills", what error are you getting (Apache log for instance)?

Comment: This code definitely works. Are you sure you aren't trying to access login() from outside of scope?

Comment: I agree: http://codepad.org/TYevTaE4

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Access to undeclared static property: MyClass::$myVar

Comment: I can set self:$myVar inside login(), but once I'm in createDBInstance, it kills

Comment: well, i found out if i removed the static from createDBInstance, it works just fine. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
private static $myVar;
```

and

```
self::$myVar = 'someValue';
```

Note the `$` characters.

Comment: sorry typo...they both have $

Comment: Okay. Can you get an error message, either on page or in a log file? That would probably help. Also maybe show the code where you invoke `createDBInstance`.

Comment: PHP Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: MyClass::$myVar

Comment: You have declared the property as private. By way of testing you might make the property public just to see what happens. If all of a sudden you don't get that error message any more then you are almost surely trying to access the property from outside the class in some part of your code that you haven't shared with us yet. The error message indicates the file and line number. They should point you in the right direction.